# $Pic^0$ as Ker of the first Chern class in connection with homological equivalence

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Griffiths-Harris, *Principles of Algebraic Geometry*, page 457, it says that the kernel of the first Chern class $c_1:Pic(M)\cong H^1(M,\mathcal O^*)\longrightarrow H^2(M,\mathbb Z)$ is the space of divisors homologous to $0$ (everything up to linear equivalence).

Why is this true? The kernel of $c_1$ should be $Pic^0\subset Pic$, but I fail to see why it corresponds to homological equivalence, and therefore why $$rk ({\rm Im} \ c_i)=rk\frac{\mbox{divisors on $M$}}{\mbox{homological equivalence}}.$$
The answer to the question [Neron-Severi group as the image of first Chern class](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1583320/neron-severi-group-as-the-image-of-first-chern-class) does not solve the problem, unfortunately.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think this is just the definition of homological equivalence : a divisor $D\in\operatorname{Pic}$ is homologically equivalent to $0$ iff $c_1(D)=0$.

Comment: Oh, ok. Then the question is: why does algebraic equivalence (Griffiths-Harris page 461) imply homological equivalence?

Comment: That is another question. This is more or less the invariance by homotopy of cohomology. If $D_0,D_1$ are algebraically equivalent, there is a "continuous deformation", that is a divisor $D\subset M\times X\rightarrow X$ such that $X$ is connected and $D_0,D_1$ are two fibers (over $p_0,p_1$). Let $c:[0,1]\rightarrow X$ a path linking $p_0$ and $p_1$. We have $H(M)=H(M\times [0,1])$ and $[D_0]=i_0^*[D]=i_1^*[D]=[D_1]$. Hence, $D_0$ and $D_1$ are homologically equivalent (here $i_0,i_1$ are the inclusion $M\times\{i\}\subset M$).

Comment: Ok, now I see that they are homologically equivalent. But why do they have the same Chern class? Thanks.

Comment: This is because they are divisors : the class of $D$ is $[D]=c_1(\mathcal{O}(D))$. This is not true for cocycles of higher codimension. (This is proposition 1 p141 of Griffith-Harris)