# The relationship between $J(X)$ and Pic$^0(X)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

If $X$ is a non singular plane curve, what is the relationship between the Jacobian variety of $X$ $J(X)$ and the Picard group of divisors of degree 0 i.e. Pic$^0(X)$?

I read somewhere that $$ J(X) = \text{Pic}^0(X) $$ but I can't quite make sense of this.
Please does this make sense? And why does it make sense if it does?

Comment: What is your definition of J(X)? In many sources, this is true by definition.

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** "Please does this make sense? And why does it make sense if it does?"

**Answer:** If $X$ is any scheme you may let $Pic(X):=H^1(X, \mathcal{O}_X^*)$ where $\mathcal{O}_X^* \subseteq \mathcal{O}_X$ is the "sub sheaf of multiplicative units".
With this definition it follows $Pic(X)$ is an abelian group, isomorphic to the group of iso-classes of invertible sheaves on $X$ with tensor product as multiplication. There is no direct and "elementary" way to introducing the structure of a "scheme" on $H^1(X, \mathcal{O}_X^*)$

When speaking of the "Jacobian variety/scheme" $J(X)$ you are speaking about an abelian variety/scheme. This scheme is defined as the "unique scheme representing the Picard functor". In your case of a regular curve $C$ over a field $k$, let for any scheme $T$ over $k$, $Pic(C \times_k T)$ denote the group of invertible sheaves $L$ in $C \times_k T$ whose restriction to eaxch fiber $C_t$ has "degree $0$". There is a canonical projection map $p: C \times_k T \rightarrow T$, and we get a canonical map

$$p^*: Pic(T) \rightarrow Pic(C\times_k T).$$

Define $Pic^0(C/T):=Pic^0(C\times_k T)/p^*Pic(T)$. By definition $Pic^0(C/T)$ is an abelian group for all $T$.

The Jacobian scheme $J(C)$ is the uniques scheme representing the functor $T \rightarrow Pic^0(C/T)$. It is a non-trivial theorem that $Pic^0(-)$ is a representable functor.

It follows we get a well defined functor

$$Pic^0(C/-): Sch(k) \rightarrow Ab$$

where $Ab$ is the category of abelian groups and hence $J(C)$ is an abelian scheme.
Since $J(C)$ represents a functor, it comes equipped with a universal family of invertible sheaves $L\in Pic^0(C/J(C))$. Theorem IV.4.11 in Hartshorne says that for an elliptic curve $E$ it follows there is an isomorphism

$$E \cong J(E)$$

hence an elliptic curve is its own Jacobian scheme. An elliptic curve is a one dimensional abelian variety. Let $(E,p_0)$ be an elliptic curve with $p_0$ the unit for the addition and let $L_{uni}:=L(\Delta)\otimes p^*L(-p_0)$ where $\Delta \subseteq E \times_k E$ is the diagonal and $p,q:E\times_k E\rightarrow E$ are the projection maps. It follows $L_{uni}$ is the universal family.

**Example:** If $k$ is the complex number field and $\Gamma \subseteq k^2$ is a lattice, you may (as in Hartshorne, Thm.IV.4.16) construct an elliptic curve over $k$ using the "quotient" $E(\Gamma):=k^2/\Gamma$. This construction only works over the complex numbers. You cannot construct elliptic curves over arbitrary fields using a "lattice". Over the complex numbers all elliptic curves may be constructed as $E(\Gamma)$ for some $\Gamma$.